# How to fetch a range of items from the database

Tags: ios, core-data

How do I fetch, say, item 7 000 to 7 999 in my SQLite table with around 100 000 items?

The normal fetch returns to much to work with, and I rather fetch it little by little:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Log"
                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
// here fetchedObjects holds around 100 000 rows
```

- Is there a way to specify a range with in `executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest`?
- Do I have to use the SQLite API?
- Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset` properties on `NSFetchRequest` to fetch an object in a selected range.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1000;
fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 7000;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Log"
                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
```

Comment: Awesome, is it safe? Actually another question, but is there any risk that the order could change? Say I fetch objects 7 000 - 7 999 one day, and object 8 000 - 8 999 another, when the number of objects have doubled. (I only add, never remove.) Then I need number 8 000 to be the object that once was added immediately after number 7 999.

Comment: That's entirely dependent on your fetch criteria. Are you using a predicate to filter results? How are you sorting? This is all dependent on your applications needs. As for it's safety, I don't think it would be public API if it was unsafe...

Comment: No filter, no sorting. I could sort, but I guess that was the question. So thanks! I will try this.