# gradually fetch data from CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, fetch

I'm new to using CoreData and hope my question would be understandable, if not please comment below and I will clarify if needed.

I have around 3k addresses stored in CoreData. By clicking on the catgory it fetches approximately 200/3k objects. And I list them (200 objects) in the table view. But it loads approximately for 2 seconds which is kind of slow.

I was thinking about such a solution: load 10 by 10 objects. Meaning that as soon as 10 items I loaded I display those 10 items and then I load 10 more and display 10 more items and so on.. until all items won't be shown in the table view.

This way user won't see the 2sec delay. Instead he will see 10 first items and if he doesn't scroll too fast to the bottom he wouldn't notice anything "wrong".

Is my approach correct? If not please advice something better

Btw: fields in core data are indexed.

Not sure if it will help but in case. This is how I fetch data:

```
- (void)performFetchWithCompletionBlock:(CBFetchControllerCompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
[self.context performBlock:^{
    NSError* error = nil;

    NSArray* results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray* mutableSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.sectionPredicatesArray.count];
        [self.sectionPredicatesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSPredicate* predicate, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSArray* sectionItems = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            NSArray* sortedItems = [sectionItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:self.sortDescriptors];
            if (sortedItems.count)
            {
                NSString* sectionTitle = [self.delegate sectionTitleForSectionIndex:idx];
                CBSectionInfo* section = [[CBSectionInfo alloc] initWithName:sectionTitle objects:sortedItems];
                [mutableSections addObject:section];
            }
        }];
        self.sections = [mutableSections copy];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completionBlock((error == nil), error);
    });
}];
}
```

Then completion block calls 'reloadData':

```
- (void)refetchObjectsForQuery:(NSString*)query
{
__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[self.fetchController performFetchWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (success && [strongSelf.searchBar.text isEqualToString:query])
    {
        [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
}
```

Please let me know if the question is clear enough, if no will be happy to provide details. Thanks

**EDIT**:
tried using fetchOffest and fetchLimit but the delay was still the same. 
not sure if fetchOffest was used in a correct way. I guess I need to make a fetch of 10 then reloadData and then 10 more using fetchOffest = 10 ?

**EDIT2**:
Using fetchLimit and fetchOffest doesn't help. I have set offset = 0 and limit = 1; the request still is the same ~2 secs

Comment: You may be interesting in `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672349/how-to-fetch-a-range-of-items-from-the-database). If they are indexed (and don't have "holes"), you could use a predicate on that property (`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"index >= %d AND index < %d", minIndex, maxIndex]`)

Comment: @Tung Fam : as far as I understand, you want to do pagination with core data. Have a look at this solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955486/paging-results-from-core-data-requests